# In jenkins getting this error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, selenium-chromedriver, headless, jenkins-cli

I m trying to run the selenium scripts in jenkins(@localhost) using pom.xml but facing issues w.r.t chrome driver.
Chrome Version 52.0
Selenium-server 2.53.0
Below is the complete stacktrace:

## ================================================================

Tests run: 7, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6, Time elapsed: 63.654 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
init(com.arrk.pages.AppleTest)  Time elapsed: 63.416 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages

=====================================================================
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.92 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'akshayk', ip: '10.0.2.58', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'

## =======================================================================

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at com.arrk.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.getInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:125)
    at com.arrk.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.getInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:64)
    at com.arrk.pages.TestBase.init(TestBase.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Tried every possible solution regarding this problem. If any more solution there then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to a bug report on Chrome 51-53:
[org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Exception: unknown error: unable to discover open pages](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1448)

That bug links to the main Chrome bug ["Fails to navigate to URL when Chrome 51 is launched in session 0 / through CI".](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1389#c32) Launching a Jenkins slave installed as a Windows service uses session 0.

The gist is running Chrome from session 0 broke in Chrome 51. The short term workarounds include dropping back to Chrome 50 (if you can find it), or running with the Chrome option "no-sandbox", like so:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions(); 
chromeOptions.AddArguments("test-type"); 
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox"); 
PropertiesCollection.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

A fix is expected in Chrome 54, however the bug response says they aren't planning long-term support for session 0. I am all ears if anyone knows how to launch a Jenkins slave from something other than session 0 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I used the chrome Option "no sandbox" and now it is working in jenkins. Is it the best way to run the script using "no sandbox" or it just an alternative?? @Barbara